# How to accessing payload data from request in DotNetBrowser

Tags: dotnetbrowser

I need the payload data of the request sent. How to accessing http request payload data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SendUploadDataHandler` for that purpose.

For instance:

```
engine.Network.SendUploadDataHandler =
new Handler<SendUploadDataParameters, SendUploadDataResponse>(parameters =>
{
    if ("POST" == parameters.UrlRequest.Method)
    {
        IUploadData uploadData = parameters.UploadData;
        TextData textData = uploadData as TextData;
        if (textData != null)
        {
            //This request contains text data.
        }
    }
    return SendUploadDataResponse.Continue();
});
```

See also:

- https://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/gs/network.html#before-send-upload-data
- https://github.com/TeamDev-IP/DotNetBrowser-Examples/blob/master/csharp/PostData/Program.cs

In case of any further questions, feel free to contact us at customer-care@teamdev.com